# AngularJS UI-Select as ComboBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, combobox, angular-ui-select

I'm using ui-select(version 0.18.1) plugin (in **Single Selection Mode**)

**Reference:** https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

I like the UI and features very much because we can search for option that we need from list of options that we bind to that control.

Now my need is I need this UI-Select control to work as ComboBox i.e if the searched item is not found in list of items then on pressing 'ENTER' key the item should be added to our base items list and it should be selected by default.

I need this in single selection mode, I have searched the google for this but all I could find is for UI-Select multiple mode and as tagging.

I don't need as tag in UI-Select, I need it as an option in list of options.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of this,

[issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/890) has been already raised in ui-select library in github.

It was bug - Tagging without multiple with new tags doesn't works when using angularjs 1.3.2 but it has been solved and most probably if you download latest ui-select library it has been solved this issue.

Also you can visit [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/983) one as well.

```
tagging-label="false"
```

this one might does the trick for you.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, i tried it. but couldn't get it worked.

can you please provide an example plunker or something like that

i'm using angular version v1.5.0 and ui-select version 0.18.1

Comment: Hi i have tried it again with latest ui-select version 0.19.1, and got it partially working. but it is not clearing selection on $select.clear(); and also it is showing the item as tag but i need to show it as item in list. and placeholder is not showing -None- when selection is removed in tagging mode

Comment: ok @PavanKosanam you can find it in issue of it's library there are many issues are raised... i don't know about it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

i writed additional directive ui-combobox and added some config

```
<ui-select 
  ng-model="ctrl.person.selected" theme="select2" 
  reset-search-input='false'
  ui-combobox="email"
 style="min-width: 300px" >
    <ui-select-match placeholder="...">
      {{ctrl.person.selected}}
      </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person.email as person in ctrl.people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
      <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>



    app.directive('uiCombobox', function() {
          return {
            require: 'uiSelect',
            link: function(s, e, a, uiSelect) {
              s.$watch(function() {
                return uiSelect.search
              },function() {
                if(!uiSelect.search) return;
                console.log(uiSelect.search);
                var obj = {};
                obj[a.uiSel] = uiSelect.search;
                s.$broadcast('uis:select', obj);
              });
            }
          }

        })
```